# open modal after reload page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to open modal after reloading page. I need to update the results before opening the modal again. I am using this method but it does not work:

```js
if (data == "done") {
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    html: '<?= $getTranslation->tr('success') ?>',
    confirmButtonText: '<?= $getTranslation->tr('confirm') ?>',
    showCloseButton: true
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      // location.reload();
      $('.step-6-modal').modal('show');
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Reloading a page stops JavaScript execution. You would need to do this when the new page _has_ loaded - and that means, you need a way to differentiate between a "normal" load and a reload first of all.

Comment: idk what u r trying to do but u could maybe set a boolean [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) item - `shouldShowModal`. where u set it to true when u need it, and then in the code u check if it's true. if so, show the modal. then remember to set it as false (if needed)

Comment: You appear to be rendering the page with php. Is there some reason you can't do this on the backend using a session var?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    ajaxRequest(request).then(data => {
        if (data == "done") {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                html: '<?= $getTranslation->tr('success') ?>',
                confirmButtonText: '<?= $getTranslation->tr('confirm') ?>',
                showCloseButton: true
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // location.reload();
                $('.step-6-modal').modal('show');
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is recommended that you do not send pure code as an answer. It would be a good practice to add some description about the solution you advising.